# PMD/Checkstyle reports during compilation Gradle

Tags: gradle, compilation, report, checkstyle, pmd

I am trying to generate PMD and Checkstyle reports during the compileJava and compileTestJava tasks in my gradle build. By default, the PMD and Checkstyle plugins only report bugs during the check and build phases of my project build. I cannot find the code to generate a report inside a task:

```
compileJava { // generate.pmd.report // generate.checkstyle.report}
compileTestJava {// generate.pmd.report // generate.checkstyle.report}
```

Answer (score 0):

For pmd the solution is to use a tasks finalizedBy:

```
tasks.findByName('compileJava').finalizedBy(tasks.findByName('pmdMain')
tasks.findByName('compileTestJava').finalizedBy(tasks.findByName('pmdTest')
```

combined with pmd config to enable console output:

```
pmd {
  consoleOutput = true
  ignoreFailures = true // controls if the build should fail on detecting issues
}
```